# CSS transform clipping flipped image

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML elements and their styles, the bottom left corner of the reflection is trimmed, which is undesirable. I have tried adjusting the height, overflow, margin, padding, etc. and nothing has made the entire image show. Whats the problem here in the first place? Is there anything I can do without changing the structure of the HTML?

```
//Elements

<div>
    <img id="someImage" src="some-img.png"/>
    <section class="reflection"></section>
<div>

//Styles

div {
    perspecive:600px;
    transform-style:perserve-3d;
}
div > img {
    transform:rotateY(-60deg);
}
div > .reflection{
    background:-moz-element(#someImage) no-repeat;
    transform:scaleY(-1);    
}
```

Only works in Mozilla:
http://jsfiddle.net/zorikii/RWfhc/

Comment: Browser support:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-style

Comment: Did you mean "bottom right corner"? I see nothing wrong with bottom left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested its a pretty simple solution. The -moz-element() function takes the element exactly as it is displayed on screen.

> The element() CSS function defines an  value generated from an arbitrary HTML element. This image is live, meaning that if the HTML element is changed, the CSS properties using the resulting value are automatically updated. -  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/element)

So all I had to do was add some padding to the top of the original image element...

```
img{
    transform:rotateY(60deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(60deg);
    padding-top:100px;
}
.reflection{
    background: -moz-element(#someImage) no-repeat;     
    height:400px;width:200px;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zorikii/RWfhc/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the transform "origin", like this:

```
html{
    background:black;
}
div{
    perspective:600px;
    -webkit-perspective:600px;
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;

    /* sets origin slightly higher so it just off center */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 40%;
}
img{
    transform:rotateY(60deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(60deg);
}
.reflection{
    background: -moz-element(#someImage) bottom left no-repeat;     
    height:300px;width:200px;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

Comment: Sadly, that didn't do anything. I was able to move the reflection by adding the transform-origin to the reflection class, but that was not the result I was looking for.